# How do we run desktop automation using AutoIT in a virtual machine or a headless machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, sikuli, autoit, jubula

How do we run desktop automation with freeware tools (like AutoIT, Sikuli) in a virtual machine or a headless machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoIT, Sikuli or Kantu Automation all work fine in a virtual machine (e. g. Virtual Box). If you have a problem there, please provide details.

On the other hand, these tools need a desktop - so they can not run headless. This is by design. They can not be compared with tools like PhantomJS that just emulate a web browser.

Comment: They need a desktop on the host machine but guests can usually run seemingly headless. At VirtualBox see VBoxHeadless command.